# From Curl to Postman (Dual Authorization Header?)

Tags: curl, http-headers, postman, authorization, influxdb-2

I am currently attempting to reproduce what I have done via Curl to write data into my influxDB 2.0 Server with Postman

Example:

**curl -XPOST "https://randomwebsite.com/api/v2/write?org=myORG&bucket=myTestBucket"
-u user:pasword --header "Authorization: Token randomtokenvalue" --data-raw "mem,host=host1 value=123"**

Unfortunately by importing the curl command directly into Postman shows that I have a duplicate Authorization Header. One for User:Password and one for Token. This naturally gives me Error code of 401 unauthorized access. Wonder if anyone has attempted such feat and could share their experience. Is it possible to do so? The Curl command does work for me, so I'm wondering how to replicate such.

I will of course continue to attempt and hope to share if I have managed to achieve something.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apologies. It worked without Basic authorization. Bearer Authorization is sufficient.